# Run python script using Powershell at startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, powershell

I simply want to run a couple of python files on windows **startup**. Yes I am able to create **.bat** files and run those at startup. This is running using command line (the cmd). But for certain scenario, I would like to run these files at startup time using **powershell**. Is it possible to do so?

I looked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/437790/run-python-scripts-in-powershell-directly) and couple of other threads, but I am clueless as how to do this at startup time. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.