# Windows PowerShell opens python scripts in default program

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, python

I am trying to run a python script, visible through the `$env:PATH` environment variable, whilst using a python `virtualenv` on Windows 10 PowerShell 5.1. e.g.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\matth\Dev> script.py
```

Unfortunately, instead of running through the python the python interpreter available in the `virtualenv`, it opens the file in the default program (in my case this is Visual Studio Code).

As per [this stackexchange question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/437790/run-python-scripts-in-powershell-directly), i added ".py" to the `PATHEXT` variable via the environment variable editor, and confirmed this was added by the following line.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\matth\Dev> $env:PATHEXT
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.CPL
```

Unfortunately this did not resolve my issue, as the script is still opened in Visual Studio Code, even after opening a new PowerShell instance.

As requested, below is the output of the `$env:PATH` variable in its entirety.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\matth\Dev> $env:PATH
C:\Users\matth\Dev\venv/Scripts;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\include;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2020.2.1\;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this problem mentioned in a [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346956/why-does-running-a-sh-script-from-visual-studio-open-the-file-instead-of-runnin) yesterday.

Visual Studio Code apparently sets a number of file extension associations when it is installed, so the Windows association is taking priority over the shell's `PATHEXT`.  Unfortunately, the solution in the related question won't work for you, since you need the Python exe to be determine by the `virtualenv` path, rather than "hard coded."  And while Windows 10 makes it easy to *change* an association, *removing* it entirely is not as easy.

You could go through some hackery to remove the file extension association completely (probably via Registry edits, if you'd like), but the easiest way (according to [this comment in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8687#issuecomment-240964035)) seems to be to uninstall VSCode, and reinstall with the "Register Code as an editor supported file types" option unchecked.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling without the "Register code as an editor of supported file types" worked! Thank you.